# Why was this segment cut from 'Last of the Time Lords' on Netflix?

Tags: doctor-who

Watching the episode 'Last of the Time Lords' (S3E14) on Netflix I have noticed that a short section near the end where Martha's mother points a gun at the Master and has to be talked down by the Doctor has been edited out of the episode.

Has there ever been any explanation for this content being cut from the episode and is it still present in other releases?

Comment: Recently? Because they just took Dr. Who off Netflix. :(

Comment: The season in question is still up on European Netflix until the end of this month though I noticed the change while watching some time ago

Comment: no idea but Ithink the reason they are taking them down is to either put series 8 on and specials or to put classic who on, they removed classic who to put nu who on so i wouldnt be  suprised if they repeat it

Answer (score 8):

Netflix provide on-line access to the US versions of the show which are butchered (...***sorry*** - I mean *cut*) and edited to fit the US broadcast schedule and allow for the incorporation of commercials.

The BBC lists "The Last of the Time Lords" as Series 3 Episode 13 running at 50 minutes whereas Netflix lists it as Season 3 Episode 14 running at 46 minutes:

[image]

[image]

The Episode numbering is different as the UK shows Christmas Specials which Netflix includes in a show's season.

Comment: We are Americans! Feed us commercials! _sigh..._